# Invalid Arguements/to_string not a member of std/function to_string could not be resolved

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11, mingw, sdl

So Im working a Nine Mens Morris C++ implementation with eclipse and im running into three different errors in one line. The error resides on this line

```
Interface::broadcast("Player " + std::to_string(turn + 1) + " made a mill! ");
```

this is the full statement, the same error resides on a below line but i figured if i can figure one out i can figure the other out.

```
if (result && p.getPlayState() != PlayerState::State::REMOVE) {
    if (MillCheck::check(board, a)) {
        Interface::broadcast(std::string("Player") + std::to_string(turn + 1) + " made a mill! ");
        std::cout << "Player " << turn + 1 << " made a mill! " << std::endl;
        p.setState(PlayerState::State::REMOVE);
    }
}
```

And it is giving me three different errors. one on the **"Interface::broadcast"** saying that 
**"
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
void broadcast(std::basic_string,std::allocator>)"**

and two on the **std::to_string** which both says that **"to_string is not a member of std"** and that the **function 'to_string' could not be resolved**.

My broadcast class resides in my interface class which is the following

```
void Interface::broadcast(std::string e) {
event = e;}
```

The error is on my game class and it does include the interface class. My discovery settings on the CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings is

```
${COMMAND} ${FLAGS} -E -P -v -dD -std=c++11 "${INPUTS}"
```

I am using SDL and SDL.ttf but I believe that it does not cause the error.

Comment: What's the *first* (topmost) error you get? Copy and paste it, don't retype it. (C++ errors usually need to be fixed in the order they occur, as the compiler gets very confused by them.)

Comment: @molbdnilo `Description Resource Path Location Type
'to_string' is not a member of 'std' Game.cpp /DGNineMensMorris line 64 C/C++ Problem
`

Comment: @molbdnilo i am using `#include <string>` and am referencing all classes needed in the header file.

Comment: I presume you are using a MinGW compiler environment. This is a known issue with MinGW. A version of gcc compiler later than 4.8.0 shouldn't have this issue. Probably your version is older. The relavant bug is here : https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52015

Comment: @user3493289 i am using MingGW version 4.8.1 and the error is still occurring